# Multiply decimals in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, floating-point, double, bigdecimal

I'm trying to multiply two crypto currencies together, their numbers are for example, `0.00200` and `0.00300`. I've defined them as floats, I've also tried doubles and big decimals. But I'm struggling to get the output I'm expecting.

Here's the test:

```
class MultiplyDecimalTest {

    @Test
    fun `test can multiply two decimal integers`() {
        val a = 0.00200
        val b = 0.00400
        val expected = 0.00800
        val actual = multiplyDecimal(a, b).toDouble()
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}
```

Current function:

```
fun multiplyDecimal(a: Double, b: Double): BigDecimal {
    return BigDecimal(b).multiply(BigDecimal(a))
}
```

I'm new to Kotlin/Java, so I suspect I'm using the wrong type of integer perhaps.

The actual outcome is: `8.0E-6` - I understand the E-6 is an exponent, I'd like to be able to format it like the original values as well.

Comment: Why would you expect `0.00800` when the product of these numbers is `0.000008`?

Comment: I'm terrible at maths unfortunately

Comment: OK.  Correct that error anyway, and use Louis Wasserman's answer.  It's really the only way to do this (although I might have written `assertEquals(0, expected.compareTo(actual));` at the end).

Comment: Hmmm this shows as being 1, is this a rounding issue or something?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a rounding error; it'd imply that they aren't equal.

Comment: Right okay, that makes sense

Comment: Multiplying two currencies seems like an odd operation anyway.  What are the units of the result?  Square pennies?  Normally, you might multiply a currency by a percentage, or something like that, but I can't think of a single business application of multiplying one currency by another.

Comment: In my current use case, I have one crypto currency, and I'm trying to work out how much that is in another. So if I have say... 0.0800 btc, what would that be in Ethereum, if Ethereum is currently 45.30 for one btc, if that makes sense? I'm probably way off the mark by the sounds of it

Comment: OK, so you're not multiplying two currency amounts - you're multiplying one currency amount by a conversion rate.  It's quite different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A key part of [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is that you must use it literally the whole way through: passing [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) into `BigDecimal` destroys any benefit you would get from `BigDecimal`.

You must use [constructor taking a `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)), `BigDecimal("0.00200")` and `BigDecimal("0.00400")`, with the quotes. Then call [`multiply`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply(java.math.BigDecimal)) on them.  You must not call [`doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()) on the result.

Equality testing on `BigDecimal` also adds complications, requiring exactly the same scale.  Consider using [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)) like this, `assertTrue(expected.compareTo(actual) == 0)`.

Another issue: Your math is incorrect. 0.00200 * 0.00400 = 0.000008 rather than 0.00800.

Example code using only `BigDecimal` while avoiding `Double`. In Java syntax. Corrected your inputs.

```
var a = "0.002000" ;
var b = "0.004000" ;
var expected = "0.000008" ;

var actual = new BigDecimal( a ).multiply( new BigDecimal( b ) ) ;
actual = actual.setScale( new BigDecimal( a ).scale() ) ;  // Set scale of result to match the scale of inputs.
boolean matching = actual.equals( new BigDecimal( expected ) ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Idqphj).

> actual: actual: 0.000008
>
> matching: true

Comment: Furthermore, [0.00200 * 0.00400 = 0.000008](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=0.00200+*+0.00400&t=osx&ia=calculator)  rather than 0.00800.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense, thank you! Much appreciated

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm trying to multiply two currencies, which are in this format: 0.00000374 for example

Comment: @EwanValentine Never use floating-point types (`float`/`Float`, `double`/`Double`) for money matters. Floating-point technology [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed-of-execution. Accountants prefer accuracy.

Comment: @EwanValentine Tip: Be very aware of your scale and use of rounding modes while doing such calculations. Ask your responsible party about their specification for both: (a) scale such as to the penny or to the tenth of a penny and (b) rounding mode such as [banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Comment: It's kind of cheating, to rig the number of zeroes in the inputs in your example code, and these don't match OP's original inputs.  It would be nicer if the assertion in the example code used `compareTo` instead of `equals`, as per the text of the answer, and the inputs were the same as the OP gave.